# Get offsetHeight after manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I wrote the following code:

```
var image_pinch_help = document.getElementById("image_pinch_help");
var pinch_img_el = document.getElementById("pinch_img_el");

function openImage(img_url) {
  pinch_img_el.src = img_url;
  if (pinch_img_el.complete) {
    IMGloaded();
  }
  else {
    pinch_img_el.addEventListener('load', IMGloaded())
    pinch_img_el.addEventListener('error', function() {
        alert('error')
    });
  }

  image_pinch_help.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("pinch_values").setAttribute("content", "");
}

function IMGloaded() {
  var screen_height = window.screen.height;
  console.log("HERE IS THE HEIGHT: " + screen_height);
  var img_height = pinch_img_el.offsetHeight;
  console.log("HERE IS THE IMAGE: " + img_height);
}
```

The code starts at the function `openImage()`. This function is called to open an Image at my webpage. So the image gets the full width of the screen. The screen where the image is shown on is `image_pinch_help`. You see that I make this screen visible. To allow the user to zoom into the image I am manipulation the HTML DOM, that the user can scroll at the whole page. I do this here: `document.getElementById("pinch_values").setAttribute("content", "");`.
When the Image loaded I need to get the height of the screen, which works perfectly. But I also need to get the height of the loaded image. The problem is that its always returning an empty string. I read a long time ago that this could be caused by HTML DOM Manipulations.
But how to fix this disaster?
~Marcus